# How to insert array into mysql database (column and values is array) in java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, arrays

I am having trouble with my code, when I want to save an array into the mysql database, which is an array of columns and values.

the problem is that the query I wrote does not have an error message but the data array is not stored in the database, maybe something is wrong in my query, or is this query incorrect when the column and its value are arrays.

is there any suggestion how to query if columns and values ​​are arrays in a single query?

here is my insert code:

```
while (resultSet.next()){
     for (int columnIndex =1; columnIndex <=columnCount; columnIndex++){

            roll[columnIndex] = metaData.getColumnName(columnIndex);
           isi[columnIndex] = cipher.toString();
           String masuk = "Insert into "+jComboBox2.getSelectedItem()+ " (?) VALUES (?)";       

            kolom= con.prepareStatement(masuk);
            kolom.setString(columnIndex,roll[columnIndex]); 
            kolom.addBatch();
            kolom.executeBatch();

            value= con.prepareStatement(masuk);
            value.setString(columnIndex,isi[columnIndex]); 
            value.addBatch();
            value.executeBatch();

         }
  }
```

and this is the code where I get the array :

```
 try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem(),"root","");
        String sql = "Select * From "+jComboBox2.getSelectedItem(); 
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet resultSet = pst.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();  
        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();



            while (resultSet.next()) {

            //perulangan untuk menghitung jumlah isi kolom dalam tabel
                for (int columnIndex =1; columnIndex <=columnCount; columnIndex++){
            //inisialisasi 
                    roll[columnIndex] = resultSet.getString(columnIndex);
                    String key = jTextField2.getText();
                    init_Box(key, key.length());
                    plain = roll[columnIndex];
                    generate_chiper();
                    System.out.println(cipher.toString());
                    isi[columnIndex] = cipher.toString();

                    } 

            }
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Please read the [ask] article for help on writing a question we can answer.

Comment: What is the output of the final query string that gets executed with this code?

Comment: "having trouble" isn't an error message or problem description anyone can fix. What kind of trouble exactly? Do we get points for guessing?

Comment: the problem is that the query I wrote does not have an error message but the data array is not stored in the database, maybe something is wrong in my query, or is this query incorrect when the column and its value are arrays.

is there any suggestion how to query if columns and values ​​are arrays in a single query?